# Accessing NEW and OLD in mysql triggers with an variable column name?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

Is it possible to declare a variable in a mysql trigger and use the variable to access a field value with NEW and/or OLD?

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TestTrigger AFTER UPDATE on ARTICLE
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
   DECLARE fieldname VARCHAR(40);
   SET fieldname = "my_field;

   UPDATE ARTICLE
   SET foo = NEW.[my_field]
   WHERE ArtID = NEW.ArtID;  
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you can't and not only dynamically referencing column names of a row being updated by a trigger using `OLD` and `NEW` but **also you can't execute any DML statement (in your case `UPDATE`)** on the same table on which you defined your trigger.

Comment: ah I missed that - have deleted my answer.